# Сервис получения координат города

Tags: xml, json, php

Кто-нибудь знает какие-нибудь онлайн сервисы определения координат городов по названию?
API google и яндекс не предлагать, в виду слишком маленького ограничения запросов в день.

Только обязательно с API и выдачей в xml или json

Буду признателен любой информации.

Comment: У яндекса нужна регистрация, получение ключа и прочая мутотень. А у гугла всего 2500 запросов в сутки.

А мне это надо в принципе единоразово. Есть база городов мира (17,5 тысяч), надо заполнить поля их координат.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

а разве геокодер ограничен по запросам в еденицу времени?

почитал доки яндекса - не нашел ограничений